# Disable new tab button in Browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

[image]

Actually i have been creating online examination module using php. but what the requirement is i want to disable opening new tab so the users who are taking online examination will not be able to open new window untill the exam is finished..so that users cannot open new window to avoid cheating by googling

Comment: Maybe with a browser extension, but good luck getting them to install that.  I'd just watch for a change in the focus of the page -- then they couldn't look up stuff on their saved files either.  All that said, if the student has got an internet-enabled phone or tablet, what will you do? ;)

Comment: I think you can't do that, you should open a new window instead. You cant prevent them from cheating, because they may open other browser, what you can do is to put a timer so that they wont have much time to search

Comment: Hm.. May be the user has more than one browser? How can you prevent to  opening new browser?

Comment: or any other alternative

Comment: Design the questions such that they require application of mind and knowledge rather than googling and copy/paste. Ask unique questions. Thats more practical.

Comment: You can add popup windows for exam part. [like][1]


  [1]: http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_popup_window_code.cfm

Comment: but new tab can be opened from original window na

Comment: @namratha nope. You can customize that check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way would be to open a pop up window and load the test in that pop up.

Use `window.open()` and then you can provide additional parameters. [as provided here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

That way user will not able to open new tab on that pop up. Also what you can do is close the tab from which new pop up has been opened

Comment: but in new pop up window also tabs can be opened na

Comment: no, you cannot open new tab in pop up. go to this website [http://reliancenetconnect.co.in/](http://reliancenetconnect.co.in/) and click prepaid balance from left menu and see the pop up coming out.

Comment: But how to close original window..becoz window.close is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to open your new window

```
function OpenPopUpwindow(){
window.open('your url','popUpWindow','fullscreen=yes, resizable=no,scrollbars=yes
            , toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no, directories=no
            , status=no');
}
```

[window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open)